# Meaning of "reinforce that approach"

Tags: meaning

I want to rephrase the following sentence:

"Reinforce that approach with the language you use."

The sentence is taken from a guide for facilitators.

Comment: Is the guide telling you to speak that way for your benefit or the benefit of students? Without further context I cannot be sure. Can you provide some context?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is perfectly clear to me, so I'll just explain what it means. Consider the following observation:

> "The smart way to keep people passive and obedient is to strictly
>   limit the spectrum of acceptable opinion, but allow very lively debate
>   within that spectrum. That gives people the sense that there's free
>   thinking going on, while all the time the presuppositions of the
>   system are being reinforced by the limits put on the range of debate."
>   - Noam Chomsky (b.1928)

Does this make it clear to you what it means for language to "reinforce" a particular approach? Some other quotations that are getting at the same idea:

> "When we confine our debates to the merits or demerits of particular
>   executive orders, we are tacitly accepting arbitrary rule." - Thomas
>   Sowell (b.1930)
>
> "In the animal kingdom, the rule is eat or be eaten. In the human
>   kingdom, define or be defined. Every disagreement in the world is a
>   matter of definition and degree." - Kaylanis Law
>
> "The battle for the world is the battle for definitions." - Beverley
>   Eyre

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the guide is asking you to speak with that language so that others follow your lead. The guide is essentially saying: "**Demonstrate** that approach with the language you use."

Reinforce in this context would just mean that the guide is asking you to speak that way so that others will follow your example.

Answer (score 0):

*Reinforcing that approach means that appapprch is being strengthen.for example :If govt is adopting digital means that results to reinforce various schemes. *

Comment: Welcome to ELU, A Mohan.  It's not entirely clear what you're trying to say.  Please provide more of an explanation with sources to justify your answer, and take a [tour] or read the [FAQ] for suggestions on how to answer.  Enjoy!

Comment: Reinforcing something means you are strengthening something. Let's say ,you are reinforcing some skill.,it  means you are gaining strength over that .I would like to express meaning etymologically .Re +In+Force ---" in " means inside and force means you are pushing ...So you can get a sense of pushing something inside in order to get hold of that. One more thing , Reinforcing is not natural .Like I don't enjoy to going gym yet I go to reinforce my body. I hope you get this idea .